# Skipping sections dynamically in a regular expression

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation, parentheses, regex-greedy

I'm trying to develop a regular expression that will match up to the first period in a sentence- so long as that period is not inside of any parentheses.

So, for example, the string:

> Tom (Ed.) went down to the shop where the owners (J. Guys, A. Owner, and B. Ains) gathered.  It was a great night.

Should return:

> Tom (Ed.) went down to the shop where the owners (J. Guys, A. Owner, and B. Ains) gathered.

However, I find that using a lazy approach, I only get:

> Tom (Ed.

And, using a greedy approach, obviously I get the whole sentence.  Not all sentences are structured like this (some sentences have no parentheses, for example), and I've tried using negative lookup, but I don't particularly understand it.

Anyone have an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: What regex engine/tool/language are you using? Do you care or expect nested parenthesis?

Comment: I'm using Java's Pattern tools.  I don't expect nested parenthese, no, though there's the possibility of more than one set of parenthese per match.

Comment: A classical approach would be to create a (non-)capturing group that either matches a set of parenthesis or any character. See demo https://regex101.com/r/nN7wX6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in Java to match the period that is not inside the round brackets:

```
(?=([^(]*\([^)]*")*[^)]*$)\.
```

And to match the whole `Tom (Ed.) went down to the shop where the owners (J. Guys, A. Owner, and B. Ains) gathered.` sentence, you can use

```
.*?(?=([^(]*\([^)]*")*[^)]*$)\.
```

Have a look at a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD3uD0/2). Also, in Java, you will have to double-escape slashes:

```
 String pattern = ".*?(?=([^(]*\\([^)]*")*[^)]*$)\\.";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
[^().]*\([^)]*\)[^().]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA5dC0/2)

This pattern contain 3 part :

2 part `[^().]*` that will match any length of any string except `()` and dot

and `\([^)]*\)` that will match the parenthesis with a content.

Comment: This is close to what I wanted- but it doesn't match if there are no parentheses at all, it looks like.  Thank you for contributing, though, and I'll definitely be studying your answer.